# Problemas con tareas de Gulp

Tags: nodejs, npm, gulp, gulp-sass

Tengo problemas al intentar ejecutar tareas de gulp.
Tengo las dependencias de desarrollo en el proyecto, y también esta instalado como dependencia global sin embargo no puedo ejecutar el comando gulp --tasks.

[image: Resultado de usar gulp --tasks]

Y pareciera todos los comandos de gulp me fallan por que si quiero verificar su version me aparece lo mismo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando me deberia dar este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al querer ejecutar una tarea en gulp (nombre de la tarea) , me crea una carpeta completa con el nombre de la carpeta cuando solo espero un console.log();

```
const {series} = require('gulp');

function hola(){
    console.log('Hola mundo en Gulp');
};

hola();

exports.hola = hola;
```

Y me arroja esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me crea una carpeta con el nombre de la funcion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando debería hacer esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]